# Relation between a linear second order differential equation and Riccati special differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Consider the following differential equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[N(x)\frac{dw}{dx}\right]+\sigma^2\rho(x)w=f(x,\sigma),~~ 0<x<l,
\end{equation}
$0<N\in C^1(0,l)$, $0<\rho\in C(0,l)$, with boundary conditions
$$
w(0,\sigma)=u(\sigma),~ w(l,\sigma)=0,~~ \sigma\in\mathbb{R},
$$
Transformation
$$
w(x,\sigma)=\exp\left[\int\frac{\nu(\xi,\sigma)}{N(\xi)}d\xi\right],
$$
reduces the homogeneous equation into Riccati differential equation
$$
\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{N}\nu^2+\sigma^2\rho=0.
$$
It has order one, therefore $\nu$ contains one integration constant, say, $c$.

When I pick particular $N$ and $\rho$, the fundamental solutions of initial equation are nothing else, but
$$
w_1(x,\sigma)=\exp\left[\int\frac{\nu(\xi,\sigma;c=0)}{N(\xi)}d\xi\right],~ w_2(x,\sigma)=\exp\left[\int\frac{\nu(\xi,\sigma;c=l)}{N(\xi)}d\xi\right].
$$
Is there a way to prove this rigorously in general?

I thought to prove that the Wronskian is not trivial for those functions:
$$
W\left[w_1,w_2\right]=\frac{\nu(x,\sigma;c=l)-\nu(x,\sigma;c=0)}{N(x)}\exp\left[\lambda+\mu\right]\neq0,
$$
since $\nu(x,\sigma;c=l)-\nu(x,\sigma;c=0)\neq0$ a.e. in $0<x<l$, in which
$$
\lambda=\int\frac{\nu(\xi,\sigma;c=0)}{N(\xi)}d\xi,~~ \mu=\int\frac{\nu(\xi,\sigma;c=l)}{N(\xi)}d\xi.
$$
But this is the case also for $c=0$ and any $0<c<l$. So, I got stack.

**Edit:** Particular $N$ and $\rho$ are such that $N(x)=N_0g(x)$, $\rho(x)=\rho_0g(x)$, $N_0>0$, $\rho_0>0$.